# Will use of imputed values by regression imputation cause multicollinearity?

Tags: regression, data-imputation

If I want to regress y on some variables, one of which contains missing values. For example, regress the price of a rental house on its size, location, Wifi(dummy), (number of) bedrooms, neighbours' ratings which contain missing values. Then I impute the missing values of ratings by regression imputation with size, location, Wifi, bedrooms as independent variables. And then I use all these variables including ratings as independent variables to predict the price. I wonder in this case, whether there would be the multicollinearity issue if I could find a strong significance level after regressing ratings on other variables?

Comment: What have you tried to do to solve your question? From the looks of it, you could already have run the scenario you described with freely available datasets. With regards to your question, using all relevant variables in the imputation model is standard practice.

Comment: There are many problems related to imputation of missing values. Adding multicollinearity is usually not among them.

Comment: @Kuku Thank you for your comment! I am trying to do two things: impute the missing values of the variable ratings, which cannot be removed; regress price on other variables to build a prediction model for price. In this case, because I think impute ratings by means of regression imputation is relatively proper. Then, it kind of aroused my concern about the multicollinearity.

Comment: @MichaelM Thank you for your comment! I try to increase the accuracy of the prediction model, thus concerning about the multicollinearity. What if I have about 20% of the observations contain the imputed values, do you think whether it is still plausible that I can further do the regression with all variable on price? Or should I use other imputation methods, such as kNN?

Comment: You don't describe the amount of missingness. Another more technical consideration involves Little and Rubin's characterization of the *mechanism* underlying the missingness as MAR, MCAR, and so on, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_data  That said, before doing any imputation, it would be useful to build a model on the data *as it is*. This model would be based on complete information data only and would provide a benchmark wrt collinearity. After imputing missing values, compare the means and std devs of the nonmissing with the imputed information. They should be close.

Comment: If you are concerned with p values et al, you might want to look at *multiple* imputation methods. They try to avoid overconfident standard errors.

Comment: @MikeHunter Thank you for your comment! I have only one variable, which contain about 20% missing values. Actually I have read some about this missingess mechanism. I believe the variable that I want to impute is much close to MAR. But I got inspiration from your idea about the comparison of means and std devs. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelM Yes, I think so. Actually I am thinking about the pros and cons of three methods: regression ,kNN and MI. I think kNN also has pros when I want to take some geographical factors into consideration. Maybe MI would work. Thanks!

Comment: In addition, compare collinearity between the first, complete information model and the imputed information model for insight into your original question.

Comment: @MikeHunter Will have a try now. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think comments offered go a bit further than the question you ask. If I understand you well, you ask whether replacing missing values of one predictor by values fitted by regressing it on other predictors will increase collinearity.

If you use linear regression, I would think quite likely the answer would be *yes*, as at least for part of the observations you are introducing an exact linear relationship between regressors. A possible cure for that would be (as has been suggested) to use multiple imputation.

Comment: That's exactly what I am thinking about. I believe there would be collinearity, just not knowing how far the influence would go. I would probably use multiple imputation.Thank you for your answer! :)